# Getting Date only not Time from Oracle Database in PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I have following Oracle View:
[image]

**View Data:**
[image]
And I am using PHP as a backend to fetch data from the above view.
**PHP code for fetching data from Oracle database:**

```
<?php
   include 'dbconn/dblims.php';
  
  $output=array();
  $sql = "select  HEAT_ID,HEAT_NO,SAMPLE_NO,REPORT_DATE,SHIFT,C,SI,S,PH,MN,AL,N,NB,V,TI,CU,CR,NI,MO,B,CA,CE,CASTER_NO,SECTION,PLANNED_GRADE,GRADE,REASON_OF_DEVIATION from( SELECT * FROM LM_HEAT_GRADE_SUMMARY_VIEW where  heat_no not like '%x%' ORDER BY REPORT_DATE DESC) where rownum<=50";
  $parse = oci_parse($connlims, $sql);
  oci_execute($parse);
  while ($row = oci_fetch_array($parse))
  {
      $output[]=$row;
   } 
   $records["data"]=$output;
   echo json_encode($records);
?>
```

**JSON Output:**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "0": "181704",
      "1": "22302662",
      "2": "22302662/1",
      "3": "24-FEB-23",
      "4": "B",
      "5": ".11",
      "6": ".136",
      "7": ".012",
      "8": ".025",
      "9": ".48",
      "10": ".0211",
      "11": ".0057",
      "12": "0",
      "13": ".001",
      "14": ".002",
      "15": ".01",
      "16": ".01",
      "17": ".006",
      "18": "0",
      "19": ".0003",
      "20": ".0019",
      "21": ".19",
      "22": "1",
      "23": "Billets",
      "24": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "25": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "26": null,
      "HEAT_ID": "181704",
      "HEAT_NO": "22302662",
      "SAMPLE_NO": "22302662/1",
      "REPORT_DATE": "24-FEB-23",
      "SHIFT": "B",
      "C": ".11",
      "SI": ".136",
      "S": ".012",
      "PH": ".025",
      "MN": ".48",
      "AL": ".0211",
      "N": ".0057",
      "NB": "0",
      "V": ".001",
      "TI": ".002",
      "CU": ".01",
      "CR": ".01",
      "NI": ".006",
      "MO": "0",
      "B": ".0003",
      "CA": ".0019",
      "CE": ".19",
      "CASTER_NO": "1",
      "SECTION": "Billets",
      "PLANNED_GRADE": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "GRADE": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "REASON_OF_DEVIATION": null
    },
    {
      "0": "181702",
      "1": "12302663",
      "2": "12302663/1",
      "3": "24-FEB-23",
      "4": "B",
      "5": ".2",
      "6": ".196",
      "7": ".01",
      "8": ".03",
      "9": "1.37",
      "10": ".0025",
      "11": ".0065",
      "12": "0",
      "13": ".026",
      "14": ".001",
      "15": ".01",
      "16": ".01",
      "17": ".011",
      "18": ".001",
      "19": ".0004",
      "20": ".0005",
      "21": ".44",
      "22": "3",
      "23": "BB3",
      "24": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "25": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "26": null,
      "HEAT_ID": "181702",
      "HEAT_NO": "12302663",
      "SAMPLE_NO": "12302663/1",
      "REPORT_DATE": "24-FEB-23",
      "SHIFT": "B",
      "C": ".2",
      "SI": ".196",
      "S": ".01",
      "PH": ".03",
      "MN": "1.37",
      "AL": ".0025",
      "N": ".0065",
      "NB": "0",
      "V": ".026",
      "TI": ".001",
      "CU": ".01",
      "CR": ".01",
      "NI": ".011",
      "MO": ".001",
      "B": ".0004",
      "CA": ".0005",
      "CE": ".44",
      "CASTER_NO": "3",
      "SECTION": "BB3",
      "PLANNED_GRADE": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "GRADE": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "REASON_OF_DEVIATION": null
    },
    {
      "0": "181700",
      "1": "22302657",
      "2": "22302657/1",
      "3": "24-FEB-23",
      "4": "B",
      "5": ".12",
      "6": ".136",
      "7": ".01",
      "8": ".02",
      "9": ".47",
      "10": ".0263",
      "11": ".0055",
      "12": "0",
      "13": ".001",
      "14": ".002",
      "15": ".01",
      "16": ".01",
      "17": ".007",
      "18": "0",
      "19": ".0003",
      "20": ".0019",
      "21": ".2",
      "22": "1",
      "23": "Billets",
      "24": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "25": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "26": null,
      "HEAT_ID": "181700",
      "HEAT_NO": "22302657",
      "SAMPLE_NO": "22302657/1",
      "REPORT_DATE": "24-FEB-23",
      "SHIFT": "B",
      "C": ".12",
      "SI": ".136",
      "S": ".01",
      "PH": ".02",
      "MN": ".47",
      "AL": ".0263",
      "N": ".0055",
      "NB": "0",
      "V": ".001",
      "TI": ".002",
      "CU": ".01",
      "CR": ".01",
      "NI": ".007",
      "MO": "0",
      "B": ".0003",
      "CA": ".0019",
      "CE": ".2",
      "CASTER_NO": "1",
      "SECTION": "Billets",
      "PLANNED_GRADE": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "GRADE": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "REASON_OF_DEVIATION": null
    },
    {
      "0": "181698",
      "1": "12302660",
      "2": "12302660/1",
      "3": "24-FEB-23",
      "4": "B",
      "5": ".2",
      "6": ".152",
      "7": ".008",
      "8": ".032",
      "9": "1.45",
      "10": ".0021",
      "11": ".0064",
      "12": "0",
      "13": ".028",
      "14": ".002",
      "15": ".01",
      "16": ".01",
      "17": ".01",
      "18": "0",
      "19": ".0004",
      "20": ".0009",
      "21": ".45",
      "22": "3",
      "23": "BB3",
      "24": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "25": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "26": null,
      "HEAT_ID": "181698",
      "HEAT_NO": "12302660",
      "SAMPLE_NO": "12302660/1",
      "REPORT_DATE": "24-FEB-23",
      "SHIFT": "B",
      "C": ".2",
      "SI": ".152",
      "S": ".008",
      "PH": ".032",
      "MN": "1.45",
      "AL": ".0021",
      "N": ".0064",
      "NB": "0",
      "V": ".028",
      "TI": ".002",
      "CU": ".01",
      "CR": ".01",
      "NI": ".01",
      "MO": "0",
      "B": ".0004",
      "CA": ".0009",
      "CE": ".45",
      "CASTER_NO": "3",
      "SECTION": "BB3",
      "PLANNED_GRADE": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "GRADE": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "REASON_OF_DEVIATION": null
    },
    {
      "0": "181695",
      "1": "32302659",
      "2": "32302659/1",
      "3": "24-FEB-23",
      "4": "A",
      "5": ".2",
      "6": ".227",
      "7": ".011",
      "8": ".029",
      "9": "1.57",
      "10": ".0016",
      "11": ".0065",
      "12": "0",
      "13": ".028",
      "14": ".003",
      "15": ".01",
      "16": ".01",
      "17": ".011",
      "18": "0",
      "19": ".0004",
      "20": ".0007",
      "21": ".47",
      "22": "3",
      "23": "BB3",
      "24": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "25": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "26": null,
      "HEAT_ID": "181695",
      "HEAT_NO": "32302659",
      "SAMPLE_NO": "32302659/1",
      "REPORT_DATE": "24-FEB-23",
      "SHIFT": "A",
      "C": ".2",
      "SI": ".227",
      "S": ".011",
      "PH": ".029",
      "MN": "1.57",
      "AL": ".0016",
      "N": ".0065",
      "NB": "0",
      "V": ".028",
      "TI": ".003",
      "CU": ".01",
      "CR": ".01",
      "NI": ".011",
      "MO": "0",
      "B": ".0004",
      "CA": ".0007",
      "CE": ".47",
      "CASTER_NO": "3",
      "SECTION": "BB3",
      "PLANNED_GRADE": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "GRADE": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "REASON_OF_DEVIATION": null
    },
    {
      "0": "181694",
      "1": "12302658",
      "2": "12302658/1",
      "3": "24-FEB-23",
      "4": "A",
      "5": ".1",
      "6": ".154",
      "7": ".011",
      "8": ".024",
      "9": ".48",
      "10": ".0314",
      "11": ".0054",
      "12": "0",
      "13": ".001",
      "14": ".002",
      "15": ".01",
      "16": ".01",
      "17": ".006",
      "18": "0",
      "19": ".0003",
      "20": ".0026",
      "21": ".18",
      "22": "1",
      "23": "Billets",
      "24": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "25": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "26": null,
      "HEAT_ID": "181694",
      "HEAT_NO": "12302658",
      "SAMPLE_NO": "12302658/1",
      "REPORT_DATE": "24-FEB-23",
      "SHIFT": "A",
      "C": ".1",
      "SI": ".154",
      "S": ".011",
      "PH": ".024",
      "MN": ".48",
      "AL": ".0314",
      "N": ".0054",
      "NB": "0",
      "V": ".001",
      "TI": ".002",
      "CU": ".01",
      "CR": ".01",
      "NI": ".006",
      "MO": "0",
      "B": ".0003",
      "CA": ".0026",
      "CE": ".18",
      "CASTER_NO": "1",
      "SECTION": "Billets",
      "PLANNED_GRADE": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "GRADE": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "REASON_OF_DEVIATION": null
    },
    {
      "0": "181691",
      "1": "32302656",
      "2": "32302656/1",
      "3": "24-FEB-23",
      "4": "A",
      "5": ".18",
      "6": ".216",
      "7": ".016",
      "8": ".028",
      "9": "1.38",
      "10": ".0018",
      "11": ".0063",
      "12": ".001",
      "13": ".027",
      "14": ".003",
      "15": ".01",
      "16": ".01",
      "17": ".009",
      "18": "0",
      "19": ".0005",
      "20": ".0019",
      "21": ".42",
      "22": "3",
      "23": "BB3",
      "24": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "25": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "26": null,
      "HEAT_ID": "181691",
      "HEAT_NO": "32302656",
      "SAMPLE_NO": "32302656/1",
      "REPORT_DATE": "24-FEB-23",
      "SHIFT": "A",
      "C": ".18",
      "SI": ".216",
      "S": ".016",
      "PH": ".028",
      "MN": "1.38",
      "AL": ".0018",
      "N": ".0063",
      "NB": ".001",
      "V": ".027",
      "TI": ".003",
      "CU": ".01",
      "CR": ".01",
      "NI": ".009",
      "MO": "0",
      "B": ".0005",
      "CA": ".0019",
      "CE": ".42",
      "CASTER_NO": "3",
      "SECTION": "BB3",
      "PLANNED_GRADE": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "GRADE": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "REASON_OF_DEVIATION": null
    },
    {
      "0": "181690",
      "1": "12302655",
      "2": "12302655/1",
      "3": "24-FEB-23",
      "4": "A",
      "5": ".09",
      "6": ".12",
      "7": ".008",
      "8": ".021",
      "9": ".43",
      "10": ".0276",
      "11": ".0053",
      "12": ".001",
      "13": ".001",
      "14": ".002",
      "15": "0",
      "16": ".01",
      "17": ".006",
      "18": "0",
      "19": ".0002",
      "20": ".0022",
      "21": ".16",
      "22": "1",
      "23": "Billets",
      "24": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "25": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "26": null,
      "HEAT_ID": "181690",
      "HEAT_NO": "12302655",
      "SAMPLE_NO": "12302655/1",
      "REPORT_DATE": "24-FEB-23",
      "SHIFT": "A",
      "C": ".09",
      "SI": ".12",
      "S": ".008",
      "PH": ".021",
      "MN": ".43",
      "AL": ".0276",
      "N": ".0053",
      "NB": ".001",
      "V": ".001",
      "TI": ".002",
      "CU": "0",
      "CR": ".01",
      "NI": ".006",
      "MO": "0",
      "B": ".0002",
      "CA": ".0022",
      "CE": ".16",
      "CASTER_NO": "1",
      "SECTION": "Billets",
      "PLANNED_GRADE": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "GRADE": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "REASON_OF_DEVIATION": null
    },
    {
      "0": "181686",
      "1": "22302653",
      "2": "22302653/1",
      "3": "24-FEB-23",
      "4": "A",
      "5": ".19",
      "6": ".155",
      "7": ".009",
      "8": ".033",
      "9": "1.46",
      "10": ".0015",
      "11": ".0066",
      "12": "0",
      "13": ".028",
      "14": ".002",
      "15": ".01",
      "16": ".01",
      "17": ".011",
      "18": "0",
      "19": ".0005",
      "20": ".0012",
      "21": ".44",
      "22": "3",
      "23": "BB3",
      "24": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "25": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "26": null,
      "HEAT_ID": "181686",
      "HEAT_NO": "22302653",
      "SAMPLE_NO": "22302653/1",
      "REPORT_DATE": "24-FEB-23",
      "SHIFT": "A",
      "C": ".19",
      "SI": ".155",
      "S": ".009",
      "PH": ".033",
      "MN": "1.46",
      "AL": ".0015",
      "N": ".0066",
      "NB": "0",
      "V": ".028",
      "TI": ".002",
      "CU": ".01",
      "CR": ".01",
      "NI": ".011",
      "MO": "0",
      "B": ".0005",
      "CA": ".0012",
      "CE": ".44",
      "CASTER_NO": "3",
      "SECTION": "BB3",
      "PLANNED_GRADE": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "GRADE": "IS: 2062/2011, E350C (V)",
      "REASON_OF_DEVIATION": null
    },
    {
      "0": "181685",
      "1": "32302654",
      "2": "32302654/1",
      "3": "24-FEB-23",
      "4": "A",
      "5": ".1",
      "6": ".12",
      "7": ".012",
      "8": ".011",
      "9": ".49",
      "10": ".0308",
      "11": ".0056",
      "12": "0",
      "13": ".001",
      "14": ".002",
      "15": ".01",
      "16": ".01",
      "17": ".009",
      "18": "0",
      "19": ".0003",
      "20": ".0026",
      "21": ".18",
      "22": "1",
      "23": "Billets",
      "24": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "25": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "26": null,
      "HEAT_ID": "181685",
      "HEAT_NO": "32302654",
      "SAMPLE_NO": "32302654/1",
      "REPORT_DATE": "24-FEB-23",
      "SHIFT": "A",
      "C": ".1",
      "SI": ".12",
      "S": ".012",
      "PH": ".011",
      "MN": ".49",
      "AL": ".0308",
      "N": ".0056",
      "NB": "0",
      "V": ".001",
      "TI": ".002",
      "CU": ".01",
      "CR": ".01",
      "NI": ".009",
      "MO": "0",
      "B": ".0003",
      "CA": ".0026",
      "CE": ".18",
      "CASTER_NO": "1",
      "SECTION": "Billets",
      "PLANNED_GRADE": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "GRADE": "SAE 1010-Alk",
      "REASON_OF_DEVIATION": null
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output of Above PHP Code:**
[image]

**Problems with above output:**

1. Report_Date column has both date and time but i am getting date only
   in different format.
2. There is 0 before decimal in each number
   column but getting output without that 0.

Comment: _"Output of Above PHP Code:"_ - now let's stick to the actual truth here, please. That is _not_ what your PHP script returned - that was just a JSON data structure. We don't know what you are using to _view_ that JSON data in that format your screenshot shows - so we currently can't tell where in this the actual problem lies to begin with either.

Comment: @CBroe, See the JSON output.

Comment: Maybe you need to change the session NLS_DATE_FORMAT in the PHP connection to the database? It looks like it's being retrieved as a string, not as a native date; or maybe cast it to timestamp in the query? Or format it explicitly in the query?

Comment: Manual for `oci_fetch_array` says for example, _"DATE columns are returned as strings formatted to the current date format. The default format can be changed with Oracle environment variables such as NLS_LANG or by a previously executed ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT command."_, and I am guessing for number there might probably something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your php script:

```
putenv("NLS_DATE_FORMAT=YYYYMMDDHH24MISS");
```

Or whatever format you want. Then upon returning that via JSON to your browser (I'm assuming you have a Javascript front-end), you can make a real Javascript date out of it and display it however you want. For example:

```
// Javascript date
row.REPORT_DATE_MS = Date.parse(row["REPORT_DATE"])

// display nicely
(new Date(row.COMPOSITE_START_DATE_MS).toLocaleString(undefined, {dateStyle: "medium"}))
```

Comment: For best portability (ie to avoid this not working in some cases - such as if you try to set different values in the same application) it's always best to set Oracle environment variables _before_ the PHP process starts.

Comment: If the PHP process is invoked by an AJAX call, is that possible?

Comment: Yes because something must be starting the webserver that PHP is running in.

Comment: Okay, if I set the environment before starting up Apache, then I set it for everything that may go through that web server. Does that not limit the flexibility of using it for different apps that may have different format needs?

Comment: That's the general idea, though how to do it so it is passed down to PHP varies with Apache version.  Generally it's not enough to set it in the terminal that invokes Apache and it needs to be set in some Apache configuration file.   If you have different OS processes that need different values, you'll need to think about solutions.

Comment: Given the inflexibility of that, and the uncertainty of how to do it, and the common security model many companies have in which developers do not have access to manage the Apache daemon itself, I think the putenv option is after all the better method. Keeps control over your program's functionality close to (inside of) your program instead of some odd, maybe inaccessible place.

Comment: putenv for Oracle envs is subject to unexpected behaviors so it isn't great.  Note that each process will read that env var once, so if you try to change it in a later http request that reuses the PHP process, you won't get the desired result.  (And this behavior may vary with versions, whether you are using PHP-FPM, etc etc etc).  A common model for a production application would be to have the configuration appropriately made for that application; this may involve a discussion with IT. If I could magically change all this historic behavior I would!